# TimeZone changes Java and Database

Tags: java, postgresql, timezone

I want to know how we can manage time zone related changes with Java and Databases. When there is a time change in a particular country (Daylight Saving Time or Some other reason Ex. Russia change time 1 hour backward ) how we can made that change without affecting the code.

"without affecting the code" means without changing the code. Just using some configurations.

Comment: "how we can made that change without affecting the code." this question is so unclear. Can you please edit and clarify it more

Comment: Are you looking for this? http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tzupdater-readme-136440.html

Comment: @SimY4 Yes i am looking for that. Can you let me whether that type of facility available in Databases as well??

Comment: @rajitha typically in database you store dates in UTC and perform  translation after you fetch it to avoid this kind of problem.

Comment: @SimY4 Please put this as Answer to Vote :)

Comment: @rajitha Please search StackOverflow.com before posting. Your question has been covered in countless other questions and answers. In particular, read this question, [Daylight saving time and time zone best practices](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2532729/642706).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Use UTC Server-Side

Typically in database you store dates in [UTC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time). You perform date translation after you fetch it to avoid time zone change problems.

## tz database

For Java, you can obtain fresh time zone data. Download the latest version of [tzdata](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tz_database) file, also known as the "Olson database". Add that file to your JVM bundle. See [these instructions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tzupdater-readme-136440.html).

Answer (score 0):

Postgres related configurations http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/datetime-config-files.html